# RCP application is running very slow

Tags: eclipse, performance, rcp

I exported Eclipse product without generate p2 repository for windows. When I run it for the first time it was starting very slow about a minute or more.
I removed all unused dependencies.
The product includes native launcher artifacts.
I don't use any arguments when i started application.
What should I do to reduce start-up time?

Comment: Did you check your log in .metadata directory in your workspace ? what's the size of your product ?

Comment: @flafoux Size about 50-60 mb.